# Separating integration tests from unit tests in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-studio, integration-testing

I'm trying to separate out integration tests in Android Studio 0.9.

I have added the following to the build file:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

I've run into a couple of issues:

1. The task will run but it doesn't have the rest of the project files available so I get errors about missing classes. There are some Java specific solutions I've found such as:

   - http://selimober.com/blog/2014/01/24/separate-unit-and-integration-tests-using-gradle/
   - https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/08/22/gradle-test-organization/

   But I haven't been able to figure out how to get this to work with Android Studio. Various combinations of `main` and `main.output` and playing around with dependencies don't seem to work, I get errors like:

   ```
   Error:(33, 0) Could not find property 'main' on SourceSet container..
   ```

   Which makes sense as the android plugin defines its own source sets, but these don't work either.
2. The IDE doesn't recognise the directory as a test source directory. For testing purposes I changed the source set name to `androidTest` and it correctly gets the green folder icon and the tests are run along with the existing unit tests that are already defined in `androidTest`.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am getting similar java errors and test class not found errors even after following the links.

Comment: In the end I couldn't get them to work as separate test suits in a satisfactory way, I just used a single test suit.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I couldn't get tests in my SDK module to execute at all. Is there anything that I missing. I tried to execute a single test and I keep getting class not found error.

Comment: I just added an additional source directory, this is my build file: https://github.com/Philio/disqus-android/blob/master/disqus/build.gradle#L21

Comment: @Philio Did you get this working? If so, please post your answer.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I've shelved the particular project for the moment but will revisit it later when I have more time. As it stands I've still only managed to get the integration tests to run as part of the unit tests.

Comment: Where in the build.gradle file do you put this code to add the new src directory to your project?  Is it just at the end, or inside the "android" block?  And this is the project build.gradle, or the app build.gradle?  And will it automatically show up in your IDE?  I know you didn't finish, but I'm trying to work on this, and I can't even get as far as to add the integrationTest directory to show up in Android Studio.

Comment: I think you're almost there. I'm not an Android guy, but the key missing step is adding the compiled classes to the classpath of the integration tests. Interestingly, you're already retrieving the compile classes in another part of the build: within the [`androidJavadocs`](https://github.com/Philio/disqus-android/blob/master/disqus/build.gradle#L112) task.

Try using that syntax in place of the `sourceSets.main.output` that you see in Java projects.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook I think you are right, I've done this kind of separation recently.

Comment: As Android Studio supports separate testing projects now I think this probably solves the problem without too much hassle and the integration tests can simply live in a separate project.

Comment: This question is similar, but it also doesn't have an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511630/multiple-test-suites-within-android-studio

Comment: This question is also similar and has an accepted answer that might solve this issue for some people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751260/setting-up-integration-tests-in-android-gradle-based-project

Answer (score 5):

@sm4's answer works indeed for a Java module (with `apply plugin: 'java'`), but unfortunately not for Android application (`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`) nor Android library modules (`apply plugin: com.android.library`).

**But I have found a workaround:**
Create the folders for your integration tests:

```
src/integrationTest/java
src/integrationTest/res
```

Add the sourceSets for your new folders:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
        }
        res {
            srcDir file('src/integrationTest/res')
        }
    }
}
```

In a pure Java module the `java` folder would now turn green and the `res` folder icon would change. In an Android application/library module it does not.

Now create a product flavor identically named as the folder configured in the sourceSet, and it works!

```
productFlavors {
    integrationTest {
    }
}
```

And to put a cherry on top:

```
configurations {
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get the warning: `The SourceSet 'integrationTest' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin. Perhaps you misspelled something?
Affected Modules: app`

Answer (score 1):

I've done exactly this kind of separation in Gradle, but for a pure Java project, not Android. You are not specifying the classpath in source sets, which I think is the issue. Here's the relevant part of the `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    integration {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration/java')
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/integration/resources'
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

task integrationTest(group: "verification", type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}
integrationTest.dependsOn testClasses
```

IntelliJ idea picks up the folders under `src/integration` if they have the standard names (java, resources).

Comment: unfortunately this works only for the java plugin, not the android app or library plugin