# How to add a new source directory to an Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, tdd, integration-testing

So ultimately I'm trying to separate my integration tests from the unit tests in an Android Studio project.  I've found a few resources on the subject:

- http://selimober.com/blog/2014/01/24/separate-unit-and-integration-tests-using-gradle/
- https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/08/22/gradle-test-organization/
- [Separating integration tests from unit tests in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694283/separating-integration-tests-from-unit-tests-in-android-studio)

All these seem to indicate that the way to go is to create a new sourceSet for the integration tests, and then to create a new test task which builds and runs the tests in that source set.  I can't get past the first step of creating a source set which is recognized by Android Studio.

Here's what I have within app/build.gradle, which builds without errors, but does not result in an `integrationTest` source root I can add classes to:

```
android{
    ...
    sourceSets{
        integrationTest {
           java.srcDir('src/integrationTest/java')
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Where precisely do I have to add the sourceSets block?  In build.gradle? in app/build.gradle?  In app/build.gradle inside the android block?
2. Once I've added my source set in he right place using the correct syntax, is this sufficient for Android Studio to detect and present it in the UI along side the main and test sources, or are there additional steps?

**edit:**

I've attempted to follow the instructions in marius' answer, but integrationTest isn't showing up in my build variants.  Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: Build variants window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is enough:

```
android{
    ...
    productFlavors{
        integrationTest {
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding your **1st question**: The `productFlavors` block should be in your `app/build.gradle`, inside `android` block.

Regarding your **2nd question**: Once you add this to your build.gradle file, you also need to create your folders `/src/integrationTest` and `/src/integrationTest/java` . Once that is done, sync your gradle files and choose your new Build Variant from the `Build Variant` window, in order for the IDE to detect it as the active source folder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer - so now I have added the block above to app/build.gradle inside the `android` block, and I've created the folders `/src/integrationTest` and `/src/integrationTest/java`, and I have synced my gradle files.  When I go to the `build variant` window (selected from the left bar) I don't see any reference to integrationTest.  I can choose "Unit Test" or "Android Instrumentation Test" form the "Test Artifact" dropdown, or I can select "debug" or "release" from the app/build variant dropdown.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps you're choosing the 'Test Artifact' from the dropdown. There is another dropdown, below 'Test Artifact', to the right side of the 'Module-Build Variant' list. Edited my answer to include a pic.

Comment: Is there somewhere else those build variants are specified?  I have that drop-down, but the only options are "debug" and "release".  "integrationTest" isn't showing up there.

Comment: I added a screenshot to my answer to show what I'm seeing.

Comment: Just edited my answer. There was a mistake - I left 'sourceSets' instead of 'productFlavors'.

Comment: Ah ok - I think this isn't exactly what I need.  From what I understand, product flavors is intended to differentiate different versions of the application, for example for creating a separate tablet or legacy device version.  It doesn't seem like a good idea to overload this feature for integration testing, in case I want to use flavors for the intended purpose later.

Comment: The only way I managed to add acceptance test to my project was by flavors + custom configuration (acceptanceCompile). Take 'androidTest', for example - it's a built-in source folder, but under the hood it's still a flavor. However, what you're describing is unrelated to the question in hand. Product flavors is the only way, I'm aware of, for having multiple source folders.

Comment: Yeah it's not perfect but it seems to be doing the job for now