# Setting up integration tests in Android Gradle-based project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm following [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/) tutorial to add integration test env to my Android project. 
I have create `src/integrationTest/java` and `src/integrationTest/resources` dirs and then I have added this to my `build.gradle`:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/resources')
    }
}
```

But when I sync Gradle files I get this error:

> Error:(134, 0) No such property: main for class:
>   org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet Possible
>   solutions: name

What does it means? How can I solve it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have just tried with `android.sourceSets.main.output` and `android.sourceSets.test.output` instead of  `main.output` and `test.output`, respectively:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += android.sourceSets.main.output + android.sourceSets.test.output
            runtimeClasspath += android.sourceSets.main.output + android.sourceSets.test.output
            srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/resources')
    }
}
```

And now I get this error:

> Error:(136, 0) Could not find property 'output' on source set main.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved! Actually, these lines don't have to be in source set config, but in the task that runs integration tests. Now, my `build.gradle` looks like:

```
    sourceSets {
        integrationTest {
            java.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/java')
            resources.srcDir file('src/integrationTest/resources')
        }
    }

    configurations {
        integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    }

    task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    }
```

Comment: Using `integrationTest(group: 'verification', type: Test)` puts the task in the same group as the other tasks.

Comment: This solution solves the basic problem for me, but I'm using Android Studio 1.5.2 and it seems the integration is incomplete. Android Studio doesn't color the code correctly and doesn't show compile errors inline. (You need to compile the code to see where the errors are.)

Comment: I'm finding that when I attempt to use this the application classes are not available to the test classes. Is there something you're doing to get that to work?

Comment: If I use this in my Android library module, I get this: `Could not get unknown property 'integrationTest' for SourceSet container.`
When I change to `android.sourceSets.integrationTest`, I get: `Could not get unknown property 'output' for source set integration test of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet.`

Comment: @Hector When I try this I get `ERROR: The SourceSet 'integrationTest' is not recognized by the Android Gradle Plugin. Perhaps you misspelled something?`