# Multiple test suites within Android Studio

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

I have a pure Java sub-project within my Android project.  I already have a test suite located within `src/test/java`, and I wish to introduce a second test suite for integration tests.

I have specified this within my `build.gradle` as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    integration {
        java {
            compileClasspath += test.compileClasspath
            runtimeClasspath += test.runtimeClasspath
        }
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, description: 'Runs the integration tests.', group: 'Verification') {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}

configurations {
    integrationCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

with tests located within `src/integration/java`.  These tests can be run successfully from the command line, and within Android Studio, the `java` folder appears in green like the main test suite.

But when right-clicking and choosing "Run 'All Tests'", I get the errors `No tests were found`, `Empty test suite.`.

How can I have a second test suite that can be run easily from within Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

You can try by using `SuiteClasses`. For example if you have multiple Test classes in a package you can create a `Suite.class` that is running the suites you want, even all tests as long as you specify them. Then right click and run test on that class. Here is example:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
        EmailValidatorTest.class,
        NewTest.class })

public class AllTests {

}
```

Example structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted a bug for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65476541